# Bazaar folder restructuring

Tags: bazaar

I'm just using bzr for my personal project. I have a project folder, and I have several subdirectories. I firstly (mistakenly) did $ bzr init in each subdirectory, and commit many times.

Now I want to $ bzr init in the project directory, including all the subdirectories. But since each subdirectory already has .bzr thing, when I did $ bzr add in the project directory it would not include those subdirectories.

If I just delete all .bzr folder in the subdirectories then it would be possible to add them, but then I would lose all the history. I was wondering if there is any way to merge this?

Maybe my question was not specific enough. I want to pull a folder (for example, 'writing') into the folder "project/writing." Previously writing was the top level folder but I want to make project the top level and have writing as subdirectories.

I tried mkdir project, cd project, bzr init, mkdir writing, and then bzr pull -d ./writing ../writing, but it would pull the files into the project directory, not project/writing directory.

I'm very new to bazaar and sorry if my explanation is confusing.

Thank you,
Joon

Comment: Make a new directory , bzr init , and merge all your projects

Comment: It seems that when I do that the files are just added and I lose all the history. I was wondering if I can merge them with their history intact. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: It seems I could just use "join." Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see `bzr help join`:
The result is a combined tree, with the subtree no longer an independent part.
This is marked as a merge of the subtree into the containing tree, and all history is preserved.

Comment: I figured that out, but thanks. The join command is very neat.